# RSS & Atom Feed Images(Thumbnails)

Tags: java, android, rss, rss-reader

I'm attempting to make an rss feeder android app. So far I have been using the well known ROME rss to read feeds of various types. However it doesn't have any way to get images or thumbnails from each element. I figured it would be easy to do manually however it seems that there are many ways to store a thumbnail/image. Are there any libraries out there that make it easier or do I have to check each one individually? Even just a list of potential places would help quite a bit.

I'm sorry if my rss knowledge is limited I'm very new to it. Thank you!